# Python - Double backslash is not passed to command

Tags: python, python-3.x, backslash

I need to pass the following user login to a bash subprocess command, however when its passed through it returns as "domain\test" rather than a single backslash. But when i print it, it will return as a single.

```
usr = "domain\\"
u = "test"
usrLogin = ''.join([usr,u])
```

I have tried the following variations of assigning usr:

```
usr = "domain\\"    
usr = 'domain\\'
usr = r'domain\'
usr = r"domain\\"
usr = str(r('domain\\'))
```

The string is passed to the following command:
    subprocess.call(["chown", "-R", usrLogin, usrLocation])

The output i need is:

```
domain\test
```

however at the moment, when it is being passed to the subprocess call it is showing as:

```
domain\\usr
```

However when i call print it will only show with 1 backslash:

```
print('usrLogin)
domain\test
```

Edit: Sorry for the confusion, i have added more detail that hopefully helps.

Comment: What specifically is the output you're looking for? `r"domain\\" == "domain\\\\"` and `"domain\\"` produce strings with both a double and a single backslash, respectively.

Comment: It is not clear from your question *which* string is being output or where or how it's being output. Are you seeing it in the result of the REPL, or are you using `print`, or something else entirely? Are you getting an error message? What do you mean by "command"? You only have code snippets here, and ordinary statements in a script aren't usually described as a "command." The exact details matter a *lot* here.

Comment: The single vs double quotes do not make a difference. The `usr = r"domain\\"` or `usr = r'domain\\'` do work. In the later case, you forgot to type the second backslash -- third line in your sample.

Answer (score 1):

usr = "domain\\"

`\` is escape character, so you've to use four slashes to get two.

Comment: Apologies, that was what i first tried. I have updated the post to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Van Peer already said the backslash is an escape character for the second backslash. So `\\` will result in `\`.

If you want to have double backslashes as a result you will need to write `\\\\`.